# Creating one system from another - java

Tags: java, security, executable, executable-jar

I'm currently attempting to make an application to store user's passwords and I've found a way to utilise system properties to prevent all other computer's from decrypting the user's files.

So I plan on storing the key in this program that is locked by the system properties. I'm wondering if there is a way of having one executable jar (my main program), collect some information (the system properties) which it then uses to create another application (my key secured with the system properties) before carrying on and doing it's own task. I understand I could create a notepad file, insert my code, save as .java and then compile using the javac command but I'm assuming the user won't have a jdk or something similar so was hoping for alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think you need to do that?

Comment: @Fildor I'd like it so that the user can't modify the system properties to change it to someone else's resulting in them having access to the system, I thought using a hard-coded key that was held in jar or similar file would be suitable

Comment: Maybe you want to put some example code. I have no idea how you would want system properties to achieve that. And security by "tricks" most often breaks within a few seconds when an experienced hacker looks at it. The alternative I would recommend to look into: see if you can store your passwords in the system keyring ... but of course that depends on your operating system.

Comment: It's still very unclear what you're after. You could use a file that contains the user's secure data and which is only accessible by the user or maintain encrypted data in a database etc. You don't need to and probably shouldn't compile (user-specific) passwords etc. into your appliction.

Comment: @Thomas The idea behind the application is to store user's passwords and memorable information in an encrypted format. The information itself would be stored in files that are encrypted, hidden and stored in a non-obvious place. However, I was hoping I could store the keys needed to decrypt the files in a more of a secure way, for example having them hard-coded into an application on the user's system that can't be modified

Comment: @GhostCat I'll definitely look into the System Keyring as that's not something I've heard of yet, and at the moment I don't even know if it's possible so there's no example code, just seeing if people could see where I was coming from and if there was any solutions similar to what I'd want.

Comment: If those keys are user-specific anyways you could either require the user to enter the key before decrypting or just let the OS only set access permissions for the user on those files.

Comment: @Thomas The decryption keys are user-specific but aren't the easiest thing to remember so I was hoping the system would "enter" it for them. In regards to the access permissions, if anyone has admin permissions they could just change the permissions on the file resulting in the file being compromised